MKLINK Sims 4 Cannot Create a File that Already Exists WHY
I was able to fix the code for the MKLINK from my last question, and I heartily thank the person who was kind enough to help me! Unfortunately, after typing everything exactly as the commenter suggested, I was told that the MKLINK "cannot create a file that already exists".
I have a brand new external drive, with a brand new downloaded file of the Sims straight from EA. The external drive is "D:" instead of my last one which was "F:". There shouldn't be a way for a file to already exist since this is brand new. If there's a simple way for me to override this so that I can finally have an MKLINK so I can use my mods again

While I truly believe you have a syntax error. You can address the close reason by editing this question to include all relevant information like which command you issue precisely and any other necessary information to answer your question. Went ahead and removed the meta commentary for you.
